# c# System.Xml.Serialization does not goes throught set method of Public List<T>

Tags: c#, xml, list, xml-serialization, deserialization

I want to deserialize back my class using System.Xml.Serialization, but i've noticed a strange behaviour using List Properties:

it never calls the set method, which lead me to loosing vital informations ...

I'd like to avoid to switch serialization method.

```
public class Category
{
    private string _name;
    private List<Category> _subCategories;
    private Category _parent;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public List<Category> SubCategories
    {
        get { return _subCategories; }
        set
        {
            _subCategories = value;
            foreach (Category category in _subCategories) 
            { 
                category.Parent = this; 
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public Category Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set { _parent = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really set the list like `SubCategories = anotherList` or do you just modify it with `SubCategories.Add(someItem)`? If you don't actually set it, the setter doesn't get called.

Comment: I do, just to take advantage of setting the parent on each of those subCategory, i've also an AddSub Method.
The List is public only for serialization purpose ...
But looks like the serialization method is doing that the other way.

Comment: You need to reconsider the SubCategories property.  Anybody can call the getter and add elements to the returned list and *not* call your setter again.  Like the xml deserializer does.

Comment: Maybe i should just use a different approach:
i should just give an uniqueId to the class instances and save that during the serialization and then recreate the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the serializer *does* set the `SubCategories` property, but it sets it to an empty list, then adds items to the list. That's why the `Parent` property of the children doesn't get set. I wrote an article some time ago about XML serialization of parent/child relationships, you can find it [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/).

Using the solution in that article, your `Category` class would look like this:

```
public class Category : IChildItem<Category>
{
    private string _name;
    private readonly ChildItemCollection<Category, Category> _subCategories;
    private Category _parent;

    public Category()
    {
        _subCategories = new ChildItemCollection<Category, Category>(this);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public ChildItemCollection<Category, Category> SubCategories
    {
        get { return _subCategories; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public Category Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set { _parent = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this make sense, but i think i will reconsider my code, to make the class more human readable or straight forward. I like to keep it simple

Comment: Thanks anyway! This enlighted me about why it was failing.
Strange fact it used to work with arrays, i think because array can't be resized, so it get setted once the subCategory is complete ...