# Saving Xml to a Document C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows, save

Unlike what I've been able to find on here I wand to maintain syntax within my xml document, and serialization doesn't touch on that. I want to be able to add another "task" tag to the xml document...Loading the information isn't a problem, I've had to deal with that before... but this is.

Main Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ToDoList
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string title; //the variable for the title textbox value to be stored in
        string details; //the variable for the details textbox value to be stored in
        string itemstr; //the variable for title and details to be merged in

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            optionsbtn.Text = "Options"; //make the options button's text options
            var items = ToDochkbox.Items; //create a private "var" items symbolizing             the Checkbox's items array
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("tasksdoc.xml"); //load the xml document         (in bin or release)
            var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("root") //go "within" the <root>     </root> tag in the file
                    select (string)c.Element("task"); //find the first <task></task> tag
            foreach (string N in q) //now cycle through all the <task></task> tags and     per cycle save them to string "N"
            {
                items.Add(N); //add the item to the checkbox list
            }


        }

        public void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            var items = ToDochkbox.Items; //create a private "var" items symbolizing     the Checkbox's items array
            title = Addtb.Text; //set the title string to equal the title textbox's     contents
            details = detailstb.Text; //set the details string to equal the detail     textbox's contents
            itemstr = title +" - " + details; //set a variable to equal the title string, a - with spaces on each end, and then the details string
            items.Add(itemstr); //add the variable itemstr (above) to the the checkbox list

        }

    private void optionsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new options().Show();//show the options form
    }
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new options().Show();//show the options form
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        optionsbtn.Text = "Options"; //make the options button's text options
        var items = ToDochkbox.Items; //create a private "var" items symbolizing the Checkbox's items array
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("tasksdoc.xml"); //load the xml document (in bin or release)
        var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("root") //go "within" the <root> </root> tag in the file
                select (string)c.Element("task"); //find the first <task></task> tag
        foreach (string N in q) //now cycle through all the <task></task> tags and per                            cycle save them to string "N"
            {
                items.Add(N); //add the item to the checkbox list
            }


        }


    }
}
```

And My XML Document:

```
    <root>
        <task>First Task - Create a Task</task>
    </root>
```

Comment: What does "wand to maintain syntax within my xml document" mean, and why do you think "serialization doesn't touch on that"?

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)"

Answer (score 0):

The class that you could use to serialize:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("task")]
    public List<string> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Placing the `XmlElementAttribute` on a collection type will cause each element to be serialized without being placed a node for the list.

Xml with `XmlElementAttribute`:

```
<root>
    <task>First Task - Create a Task</task>
    <task>SecondTask - Create a Task</task>
    <task>ThirdTask - Create a Task</task>
</root>
```

Xml *without* `XmlElementAttribute`:

```
<root>
    <Tasks>
        <Task>First Task - Create a Task</Task>
        <Task>SecondTask - Create a Task</Task>
        <Task>ThirdTask - Create a Task</Task>
    </Tasks>
</root>
```

I answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122870/always-empty-when-using-deserialize-on-xmlserializer/11122994#11122994) about serializing lists in a similar way a few days ago.  Check out his question and then the answer, it might be what you are trying to do.

Comment: How do I use this class or what ever? Like, what does the "Tasks" in public List<string> Tasks { get; set; } need to do...I'm really confused